# SmoothScrollToPosition not working some time in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, scroll, smooth-scrolling

In my android application sometimes smooth scroll works but most of the time not working.
Below is my code please check and advice me. 
**Xml Code in this Link**.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZJnXh2d74_vd-fv_sYsoHAMNmTXxW5P3/view?usp=sharing
Thanks

[image]

Comment: can you share your xml file also.

Comment: Please Check Xml File.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZJnXh2d74_vd-fv_sYsoHAMNmTXxW5P3/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Use LayoutManager to smooth scroll

```
layoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView, new RecyclerView.State(), position);
```

Comment: Already try this but not working